# Расположить текст в нижней части блока

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

учусь верстать сайт. Проблема такая: хочу расположить цену в нижней части блока, над кнопкой купить, пробовал через display:flex, vertigal-align и т.д. Не получилось, с flex вообще какая-то фигня получается, блок вертикально стоит по внизу, но по горизонтали не хочет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для более подробного вида, вот

Comment: `display: flex + flex-direction: column + space-between`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/10wdaua

Comment: @ShahrierTurdiev. код и разметку необходимо прикладывать текстом, а не картинками.